# Cylinder drawn with triangles in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, procedural-generation

It's drawing a cylinder with stacks and edges but the problem is that stacks are connected to one point instead of a new one. 
Maybe a picture will show it better:
[image: Cylinder]

And here's how I'm rendering the side because disks are rendered separately:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < edges; ++j) {
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); {
                // 0 bottom 
                glVertex3f(x + radius * cos(theta + interval), y , z + radius * sin(theta + interval));
                // 1 bottom
                glVertex3f(x + radius * cos(theta), y + y_value * i, z + radius * sin(theta));
                // 2 top
                glVertex3f(x + radius * cos(theta), y + y_value * i, z + radius * sin(theta));
                // 2 top
                glVertex3f(x + radius * cos(theta), y + y_value * i, z + radius * sin(theta));
                // 3 top
                glVertex3f(x + radius * cos(theta + interval), y + y_value * i, z + radius * sin(theta + interval));
                // 0 bottom 
                glVertex3f(x + radius * cos(theta + interval), y , z + radius * sin(theta + interval));
            } glEnd();
            theta += interval;
        }
        theta = 0.0;
    }
```

I've been trying to solve it for days and I run out of ideas. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I've changed it to be render with quads using ybungalobill advice. Now I'm struggling with UV mapping. And hopefully once this part is solved it'll be easy enough to convert into triangles. 
That's what I have now: 
[image]

And that's the code I'm using for UV mapping:

```
u = 0.0,
v = 0.0,
u_inter = 1.0 / edges,
v_inter = 1.0 / y_value;  // (y_value = height / edges)

    for (int i = 1; i <= height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < edges; ++j) {
            glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP); {
                // 0 bottom 
                glTexCoord2f(u, v);
                // 1 bottom
                glTexCoord2f(u + u_inter, v);
                // 2 top
                glTexCoord2f(u + u_inter, v + v_inter);
                // 3 top
                glTexCoord2f(u, v + v_inter);
            } glEnd();
            theta += interval;
            u += u_inter;
        }
        v += v_inter;
        theta = 0.0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float y0 = y + y_value * (i-1);
float y1 = y + y_value * i;
// 0 bottom 
glVertex3f(x + radius * cos(theta + interval), y0, z + radius * sin(theta + interval));
// 1 bottom
glVertex3f(x + radius * cos(theta), y0, z + radius * sin(theta));
// 2 top
glVertex3f(x + radius * cos(theta), y1, z + radius * sin(theta));
// 2 top
glVertex3f(x + radius * cos(theta), y1, z + radius * sin(theta));
// 3 top
glVertex3f(x + radius * cos(theta + interval), y1, z + radius * sin(theta + interval));
// 0 bottom 
glVertex3f(x + radius * cos(theta + interval), y0, z + radius * sin(theta + interval));
```

Comment: Actually I had to change y0 in // 1 bottom to y1 but I think I understand what you did there.

Comment: It's strange because you should have three vertices on top and thee on bottom.

Comment: Yeah you're right and it didn't map well. I've changed it to quads and mapped it the way you're saying and now it's working. Now I'm struggling with UV mapping.

Comment: I've done an update if you'd like to have a look please.

Comment: If your previous problem has been solved, please avoid changing the question. Instead accept an answer to the current question and ask a new one with the new problem.

Comment: As per your new question, the answer is the same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534395/uv-mapping-a-proceduraly-generated-sphere-in-opengl

Comment: Thank you. I'll bear it in mind next time. And thank you for your help.